# Bike wheel Assembly

Tags: wheels, rims

I am trying to assemble the rear wheel of my bike. I have sorted the spokes into two groups by their length. It seems like I do everything correct according to video tutorials and articles but when I put the last group of 8 spokes they appear to be longer than needed and the nipples come out of the rim by 0.5-1.0 cm. What is the reason ? Is it a common problem ?

Comment: Half the spokes on one side being too long is something I've never seen. However, you can't really tell that the spoke is too long until you've got the wheel trued and centered. Things can look very odd until you've got some tension in the wheel and the rim in roughly the correct location.

Comment: Is it possible that I have done everything correct but the last set of 8 spokes seems to  be too long

Comment: How many spokes on the wheel, total?  Are you doing the same "cross" count as the wheel had originally?

Comment: Cross pattern does sound like a good thing to check, I got this wrong when lacing my first couple...

Comment: Did you account for dishing the rear wheel for your free wheel/hub.

Comment: This (or the opposite) happens when you attach the spokes to the rim in an incorrect position, one hole further one way or the other. Also check the suggestion by @Stamfordone.

Comment: Why are you assembling a new wheel?  What components have been replaced?

Comment: I am changing the spoke pistons.

Comment: I am not really sure but maybe I am doing smth wrong with the second set of the spokes. I am building it with 3 cross pattern. So do you know a way of determining the exact hole on the hub and the rim for the first spoke of the second set to place at

Comment: How tightly are you screwing these spokes in? First time around, you should only be screwing the spokes into the nipples a couple of turns - just enough to grip. Once all the spokes are attached, it's only then that you start tightening. And for dishing purposes it is easier to tighten the non drive side first, then the drive side, then tweak things to get the wheel true.

Comment: I give only 1 or 2 full turns. So I'm sure that I dont over tight them.

Comment: Where did you get the spokes? Have you checked that they are the right length for the hub+rim and lacing pattern that you are trying to use? Have you looked at the other "how to build a wheel" questions here, or any guides other than youtube videos (that all seem to just assume you have the right length spokes)

Comment: I took a spoke to the bike shop and asked them to give me a spoke equal to that one. I have sorted the long and short spokes so I think everything is corect

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that spokes are installed correctly, it might simply be that the axle is not centered. i.e. you under tightened the spokes on the side of the rim you built causing spokes to poke out the rim on the other side.  it is important to evenly distribute mounted spokes around the rim when building a rim.